# Is there possible to use group by with case in Laravel and Postgres?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Hello I have financial_transactions table which structure looks like

```
id | user_id | amount | type
____________________________
1  | 1       | 10     | 1
____________________________
2  | 1       | 20     | 2
____________________________
3  | 2       | 15     | 1
____________________________
4  | 2       | 10     | 1
```

I want to calculate the sum of amounts by type.
type 1 is deposit and type 2 is withdraw.
my expected output should be:

```php
[
    [
        user_id => 1,
        totalDeposit => 10,
        totalWithdraw => 20
    ],
    [
        user_id => 2,
        totalDeposit => 25,
        totalWithdraw => 0
    ]

]
```

my Laravel Eloquent code looks like this:

```php
   $data = FinancialTransaction::select([
           DB::raw("CASE WHEN (type = '1') THEN SUM(amount) ELSE 0 END AS totalDeposit"),
           DB::raw("CASE WHEN (type = '2') THEN SUM(amount) ELSE 0 END AS totalWithdraw"),
    ])->groupBy('user_id','type')
    ->get()
```

output is like this:

```php
[
    [
        user_id => 1,
        totalDeposit => 10,
        totalWithdraw => 0
    ],
    [
        user_id => 1,
        totalDeposit => 0,
        totalWithdraw => 20
    ],
    [
        user_id => 2,
        totalDeposit => 25,
        totalWithdraw => 0
    ],

]
```

if I removing 'type' from group by then returns error

```
type must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

thank you in advance.
if you have any additional questions please comment and I will try to explain;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked this for Postgres and MySQL databases:

```
$data = FinancialTransaction::select([
        'user_id',
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS totalDeposit"),
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS totalWithdraw"),
    ])
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

**Additional notes for future usage:**

*Postgres*

```
CREATE TABLE financial_transactions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO financial_transactions (user_id, amount, type) VALUES (1, 10, 1);
INSERT INTO financial_transactions (user_id, amount, type) VALUES (1, 20, 2);
INSERT INTO financial_transactions (user_id, amount, type) VALUES (2, 15, 1);
INSERT INTO financial_transactions (user_id, amount, type) VALUES (2, 10, 1);
```

*MySQL*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `financial_transactions` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `financial_transactions` (`user_id`, `amount`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 10, 1),
(1, 20, 2),
(2, 15, 1),
(2, 10, 1);
```